# Jquery hide gif after one second

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I try to hide my  gif image after one second:

```
 $('input.sortInp').change(function () {
  $(this).parents('.float_left').find('.sortLoaderDiv').html('<img class="sortLoader" src="/images/icons/loading_small1.gif">');

  setTimeout(function () {
    $(this).parents('.float_left').find('.sortLoaderDiv').html("Some text");
  },1000);

  });
```

I see my gif, but it doesn't hide in my `setTimeout` function. 
How can I stop this gif and replace div text? Thanks.

Comment: Try this: 
`$(this).parents('.float_left').find('.sortLoaderDiv').hide();`
 in setTimeout function.

Comment: `$(this)` in your `setTimeout` function does not work. You have to define a variable outside of that function for `$(this)`.

Comment: Thanks, defined $(this) and it works!

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
$('input.sortInp').change(function () {
    var input = $(this);

    input.parents('.float_left').find('.sortLoaderDiv').html('<img 
    class="sortLoader" src="/images/icons/loading_small1.gif">');

    setTimeout(function () {
        input.parents('.float_left').find('.sortLoaderDiv').html("Some text");
    }, 1000);

});
```

Answer (score 1):

The best solution I can think of is to use a closure variable.

The issue is: callback to `setTimeout()` is executed separate from the main thread.

The execution context of the callback will be different so this inside the callback does not point the same object as it was outside the setTimeout, in this case the hovered `.sortInp` element.

```js
 $('input.sortInp').change(function () {
  $(this).parents('.float_left').find('.sortLoaderDiv').html('<img class="sortLoader" src="https://opensource.org/files/google.png">');
  var self = $(this);
  setTimeout(function () {
    self.parents('.float_left').find('.sortLoaderDiv').html("Some text");
  },1000);

  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="float_left">
<input type="text" class="sortInp">
<div class="sortLoaderDiv"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

When you give `html()` all the code in the `.sortLoaderDiv` disappears. Hence your input `input.sortInp` also disappears. Hence jQuery is unable to find the input `input.sortInp` in the setTimeout function. This is happening because you have selected the parent class of your selector. Correct your code so that the `input.sortInp` is not erased by `html()` method. Or else, try this,

```
$('input.sortInp').change(function () {

$('.sortLoaderDiv').html('<img 
class="sortLoader" src="/images/icons/loading_small1.gif">');

setTimeout(function () {
$('.sortLoaderDiv').html("Some text");
},1000);
}
```